# How to convert 16 bits .tiff image to 8 bits .tiff image in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing

I making App in Netbeans Platform using Java SE for Dentist.In my App i captured image using X-Ray gun and then do image process on it.First of all i want to convert 16 bits image to 8 bits image.So,how can i convert 16bits image to 8 bits image?

Comment: 16bits grayscale or  16bits per channel ?

Comment: I want to convert 16bits Gray-Scale image to 8 bits Gray-scale image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "bi" is your 16bit grayscale BufferedImage (obtained by ImageIO.read(...));

```
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(bi.getWidth(),bi.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    Graphics2D g2 = dest.createGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, null);
```